# obtener id despues de insertar un registro en sqlserver

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Como puedo obtener el id de un registro después de que se inserto en una tabla SQL, estoy trabajando con  .net y sql server, si tengo este ejemplo de stored procedure

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_Students_INS_byPK
       @student_id                     INT                      , 
       @password                       VARCHAR(15)      = NULL  , 
       @active_flg                     TINYINT                  , 
       @lastname                       VARCHAR(30)      = NULL  , 
       @birth_dttm                     DATETIME         = NULL  , 
       @gpa                            INT              = NULL  , 
       @is_on_staff                    TINYINT                   
AS 
BEGIN 
     SET NOCOUNT ON 

     INSERT INTO dbo.Students
          ( 
            student_id                   ,
            password                     ,
            active_flg                   ,
            lastname                     ,
            birth_dttm                   ,
            gpa                          ,
            is_on_staff                  
          ) 
     VALUES 
          ( 
            @student_id                   ,
            @password                     ,
            @active_flg                   ,
            @lastname                     ,
            @birth_dttm                   ,
            @gpa                          ,
            @is_on_staff                  
          ) 

END 

GO
```

Comment: El `id` lo necesitas en el mismo script sql o necesitas usar ese id en 
 tu manejador .Net?

Comment: @J.Rodríguez necesito usar ese ID en mi manejador

Comment: Luego de invocar el procedimiento de almacenado y que se ejecute , podrías hacer un `select` de la siguiente manera: `string comando = "select max(student_id) as id from Students";` y ejecutas ese `select` y te dará el id que acabas de insertar, tomando en cuenta que el campo `student_id` es de tipo `Identity`

Answer (score 2):

Hay distintas formas de hacer esto, una de ellas sería usar `SCOPE_IDENTITY`
Solo tendrías que hacer un `SELECT` después de tu `INSERT`

**Ejm:**
`INSERT INTO dbo.Students(...) VALUES(...);
 SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();`

---

También puedes usar `@@IDENTITY`

**Ejm:**
`INSERT INTO dbo.Students(...) VALUES(...);
 SELECT @@IDENTITY AS 'Identity';`

---

Una alternativa más podría ser `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`

**Ejm:**
`INSERT INTO dbo.Students(...) VALUES(...);
 SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS [SCOPE_IDENTITY];`

Comment: Es mas fiable el SCOPE_IDENTITY(), ya que se refiere a esa transacción. @@IDENTITY puede tomar el identity de otro insert en la BD que se genero entre el INSERT y el SELECT @@IDENTITY

Comment: Cierto, pero es bueno revisar todas las opciones. Como dices SCOPE_INDETITY  es la mejor ya que tiene alcance sólo para esa transacción.

Answer (score 0):

Basado en este comentario: *necesito usar ese ID en mi manejador* Quizás no es el mejor método pero obtendrás el id deseado.

```
using(SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("connection string"))
{
    cn.Open();
    string comando = "select max(student_id) as id from Students";     
    SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand(comando, cn);
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if(dr.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(reader("id")));
    }
}
```

Incluso puedes optar por no usar un `SqlDataReader` esta a opción tuya.

> Esto tomando en cuenta que el campo `student_id` es de tipo `Identity` y que solo estas ejecutando un `Insert` ya que siempre obtendrás el ultimo registro insertado, si realizas un `Update` no te resultaría ya que traerá nuevamente el último registro de la tabla.

Comment: Es que queria que el SP devolviera el id

Comment: Pues coloca esto dentro de tu `StroredProcedure` : 

`Declare @sentenencia varchar(100)
set @sentencia = "select max(student_id) as id from Students"
Exec (@sentencia)`